# Lyx + Xetex and bibliography errors

Tags: xetex, lyx, input-encodings

I'm preparing my document in Lyx
and I'd like to  use Xetex with it.

My document compiles with bibliography which misses russian words completely.

The BIB- file is saved in UTF8 encoding. The main Lyx-file has text in russian, english + some equations and math symbols.
So I ask  Lyx to compile (via Xetex) and show PDF.
Lyx processes the document, but it's message log shows numerous "Missing character" errors.
However, the main text is processed O.K.
Am I missing some option or command in Lyx preamble or anything else?

A MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt]{scrreprt}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyrtext}{%
  \fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{T2A}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textcyr}[1]{\leavevmode{\cyrtext #1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
%\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage {setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, nohead]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtext}
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=gost-numeric, bibencoding=utf8, sorting=none, language=auto]{biblatex}


\ifpdf\usepackage{graphicx}\else\usepackage{graphicx}\fi

\usepackage{comment} 
%\ifpdf\usepackage{epstopdf}\usepackage{pdfpages}\fi

\graphicspath{{fig/}}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normal}

\defcaptionname{english}{\chaptername}{Part}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\chaptername~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
%\renewcommand{\thechapterfont}{\normalsize\bfseries} % 
\renewcommand{\appendixfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
%\renewcommand{\chapterfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}   
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\makeatother

\usepackage[style=gost-numeric,backend=biber, style=gost-numeric, bibencoding=utf8, sorting=none, language=auto]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{0C__Users_1_Contacts_Documents_My_diss_All_bib_ext_2U.bib}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\clearpage

\chapter*{{\large{}\textcyr{\CYRV\cyrv\cyre\cyrd\cyre\cyrn\cyri\cyre}}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{--}

\section*{{\normalsize{}\textcyr{\CYRP\cyro\cyrl\cyro\cyrzh\cyre\cyrn\cyri\cyrya},
\textcyr{\cyrv\cyrery\cyrn\cyro\cyrs\cyri\cyrm\cyrery\cyre} \textcyr{\cyrn\cyra}
\textcyr{\cyrz\cyra\cyrshch\cyri\cyrt\cyru}}}  

\section*{{\normalsize{}\textcyr{\CYRA\cyrp\cyrr\cyro\cyrb\cyra\cyrc\cyri\cyrya}
\textcyr{\cyrr\cyra\cyrb\cyro\cyrt\cyrery}}}

\chapter{{\large{}\textcyr{\CYRL\cyri\cyrt\cyre\cyrr\cyra\cyrt\cyru\cyrr\cyrn\cyrery\cyrishrt}
\textcyr{\cyro\cyrb\cyrz\cyro\cyrr}}}
\vspace{42pt}

\section{A}
\vspace{38pt}

\section{B}

\section{{\normalsize{}C}}
\vspace{42pt}

\chapter{{\large{}\textcyr{\CYRT\cyre\cyrh\cyrn\cyro\cyrl\cyro\cyrg\cyri\cyrya}
\textcyr{\cyrp\cyrr\cyri\cyrg\cyro\cyrt\cyro\cyrv\cyrl\cyre\cyrn\cyri\cyrya}
\textcyr{\cyri} \textcyr{\cyra\cyrt\cyrt\cyre\cyrs\cyrt\cyra\cyrc\cyri\cyrya}
\textcyr{\cyro\cyrb\cyrr\cyra\cyrz\cyrc\cyro\cyrv} }}
\vspace{42pt}

\section{\textcyr{\CYRA}}
\vspace{38pt}

\section{\textcyr{\CYRB}}

\chapter*{{\large{}\textcyr{\CYRL\cyri\cyrt\cyre\cyrr\cyra\cyrt\cyru\cyrr\cyra}}}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` is wrong with xetex.

Comment: Owww, thanks! I overlooked this  part somehow :) @UlrikeFischer